# Flutter - Deformed/overflowing custom icons using FlutterIcon.com

Tags: flutter, svg, icons

I have a few custom icons (11 to be exact) that I added to my project using [Flutter Icon](https://fluttericon.com). For most of these icons, everything is working as expected:

[image: Working icon]

However, some of them just overflow out of their intended size, or are given a wrong size. No idea what the problem is, but here is how it looks like:

[image]

as you can see, the right side of the infinity loop is just hanging outside of its intended container (`button`). Also, if I try to be hacky and resize only the infinity icon, it appears to be offsetted to the right.

I can be hacky and create a custom size for the couple of troublesome icons, but I would like to know if there is something that I, or my designer (also me) can do to fix this properly.

**Already Tried:**

- Converting to compound path.
- Removing unnecessary tags such as `<style>` tags.
- Using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package. This works okay, but it seems to be less performant that the Flutter Icon method. My app has quite a few animations running at the same time, and animating a `SvgPicture` is a little bit janky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I haven't been able to find out **why** the problem is happening, but I found out **how** to fix it.

1. After uploading your custom icons' `svg`'s into [FlutterIcon](https://www.fluttericon.com/) you'll download a `.zip` file. This file contains a bunch of files, including a `.ttf` file, which is a font file that contains your icons. You will need to manipulate the symbols/icons in that file in order to fix the issue.
2. To modify the faulty symbols, you will need to download some font editing application. [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/) does the trick. Download it and open the `.ttf` file you got from [FlutterIcon](https://www.fluttericon.com/) from it. Once you have it open, you'll see a window full of squares with `X`s in them. These are the font's glyphs.
3. You now need to find the glyphs with your icons. To save yourself from a LOT of scrolling, you can go to `Encoding -> Compact` from the toolbar. This will hide all unused (empty) glyphs. You should now be able to see all your icons. You should have something like this:

[image: Glyphs in FontForge]

4. Right click the symbol you want to fix, and click `Transform...`. You will then be prompted with a menu that will let you transform the symbol in anyway you want. Apply transforms on all your faulty icons until you are satisfied. Transform window looks like this:

[image: Transform Window]

5. Once you have finish all your modifications, got to `File -> Generate Font...`. Select the destination folder and the file name (make sure it has the same name as the `.ttf` file generated from FlutterIcons). Also make sure you the `TrueType` file type from the first dropdown menu:

[image: TrueType FontForge]

6. Once you're done, click generate, and voila! Now you have the `.ttf` file with the correctly-shaped icons. If you still find that something is wrong with the icons, you can rinse and repeat this process until you're satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [fontify](https://pub.dev/packages/fontify). it works like a charm. there is also a video that I explained how to fix corrupted SVGs that appear messed up in our custom font icons in Flutter.